# How to pass custom config to ngx-imageviewer

Tags: angular

the ImageViewerComponent(ngx-imageviewer) provided by '@hallysonh/ngx-imageviewer' only accepts custom ImageViewerConfig via providers array in @Component.

It works like this:

in wrapper-imageviewer.component.ts (my own custom class)

```
const MY_IMAGEVIEWER_CONFIG: ImageViewerConfig = {
  buttonStyle: {
    bgStyle: '#B71C1C' // custom container's background style
  }
};

@Component({
  selector: 'mtab-imageviewer',
  templateUrl: './imageviewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./imageviewer.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: IMAGEVIEWER_CONFIG,
      useValue: MY_IMAGEVIEWER_CONFIG
    }
  ]
})
```

in ImageViewerComponent (by ngx-imageviewer)

```
constructor(
    private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private _renderer: Renderer2,
    private _imageCache: ImageCacheService,
    @Inject(IMAGEVIEWER_CONFIG) private config: ImageViewerConfig
  ) {
     // code here...
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine, but the thing is I am getting custom config from another component via @Input() decorator in my wrapper class, is there a way I can pass the input config to the parent ImageViewerComponent(ngx-imageviewer) class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separated file with the content of MY_IMAGEVIEWER_CONFIG. And then import this file in providers. Because providers accepts an array.